# Improper usage of mutex c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

i have problem with my code. This function pushes a product into queue.

```
void producent(bool &cont,std::queue<std::string> &queue,std::mutex &mtx, int &milliseconds)
{
    while (cont)
    {    
        mtx.lock();
        if (queue.size() >= MAX_QUEUE_SIZE)
        {
            mtx.unlock();
            std::cerr << "buffor full " << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::string product = generate();
            std::cerr << "producent: " << product << " " << std::endl;
            queue.push(product);
            mtx.unlock();
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds));
    }
}
```

this function generates a string of 10 signs, which are pushed by void producent function().

```
std::string generate() {
    std::string temp;
    temp.resize(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp[i] = rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1) + 'a';
    }
    return temp;
}
```

My question is: why, when i create 2 threads like this:

```
std::thread prod(producent, std::ref(wykonuj),std::ref(kolejka), std::ref(kolejka_mtx),std::ref(t));
std::thread prod1(producent, std::ref(wykonuj), std::ref(kolejka), std::ref(kolejka_mtx), std::ref(t));
```

both of them give me same result, for example the outcome is:

```
producent: qweasdzxca
producent: qweasdzxca
```

i wanted those outcomes to be different, thats why i used mutex, but it didnt work. Can someone give me some advices?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161322/using-stdlibs-rand-from-multiple-threads

Answer (score 1):

`rand` doesn't share a seed between threads.  Each thread has its own seed - but without explicitly setting it differently in both threads via `srand()`, it's going to be the same.

Hence, `generate` invoked by both threads will produce the same string.

The docs suggest `rand_r` is the thread safe version, but both functions are threads safe in modern implementations.

Comment: I think that's an implementation specific. `rand()` is not thread-safe. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10159747/10686048

Comment: Go look at the latest code for `rand` .  I'm pretty sure it's thread-safe these days and shares an implementation with `rand_r`.  (i.e. the docs are out of date wrt to modern platforms)

Comment: I'm not saying `rand` isn't implemented that way, I'm saying that if it is, it's non-standard. `rand_r` (which I see you added now), or a modern random class, would be the better approach.

Comment: Right - but I'm trying to explain to the OP why he's getting identical behavior between threads.  Because in all likelihood, he's using a thread-safe version of rand.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your implementation has a thread-safe `rand()` (probably unwise), both threads are using the same initial random seed (the default of 1, in this case), and thus producing the same sequence. Rather than doing that, embrace the the C++ `<random>` offerings, and as far as that goes, the uniform distribution offerings as well.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <string>

std::string generate(int n=10)
{
    std::mt19937 prng{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist('a', 'z');

    std::string result;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(result), n, [&]() { return dist(prng); });
    return result;
}
```

Executed 10x on 10x threads, this produced:

```
ysudtdcaeq
hwpeyiyyav
dlsdshltyo
pkfafhooxr
nmoxerbqpy
ydauzdvoaj
brjqjgxrgg
ezdsmbhygb
fpdgbkxfut
elywaokbyv
```

That, or something similar, should produce what you seek.

Note: the above will *not* work as-expected on platforms where `a`..`z` is non-contiguous. If you're on such a beast (typically OS/400 or OS/390 EBCDIC), an alternate solution is required.